# iOS: Firebase token returning null

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently trying to implement Firebase Cloud Messaging by following the official Firebase documents.

I have settled the certificates and the provisioning profiles with Push Notifications enabled. I have also installed all the necessary frameworks(FirebaseMessaging,Firebase) using CocoaPods and they seem to work fine.

At the app delegate, I tried to initialize the Firebase cloud messaging token with the code below.

```
let token = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!
```

I have also set GCM to enabled and there is a GCM sender id value in the GoogleService-Info.plist.

The error that I am getting is as follows:

> 2016-11-29 16:11:12.358 Firebasesample[3852:122151] Firebase automatic
>   screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics
>   setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the
>   default screen class name. To disable automatic screen reporting, set
>   the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO in the
>   Info.plist
>
> 2016-11-29 16:11:12.419:  Firebase
>   messaging not setup correctly, nil senderID. fatal error: unexpectedly
>   found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Thank you in advance for any advice/help.

Comment: Did you call `FIRApp.configure()`?

Comment: I did. Before trying to use Firebase Cloud Messaging, I have already embedded Firebase Analytics into my application and that worked fine.

Comment: Did you add an observer for the key `firInstanceIDTokenRefresh` for retrieving the most updated token? Calling `FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!` for the first time will return nil.

Comment: Sounds like an answer @chengsam! :-)

Comment: @sabrinazuraimi can you share your fixed code. I need to know how to add `firInstanceIDTokenRefresh`  key

Answer (score 4):

Was already answered in the comment without the implementation:

Make sure you follow the setup guide on https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client.

In your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` add the following method (after `FIRApp.configure()`).

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(tokenRefreshNotification(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.firInstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)
```

When your token is refreshed, it will call:

```
func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {

    guard let token = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() else {
        QL3("No firebase token, aborting registering device")
        return nil
    }

    //register your token somewhere..
    registerToken(token)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who still having problems on get the token, maybe is because the token has not yet been generated.

On the guide(https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client) you can find this part:

> When you need the current token, retrieve it. This may return null if
>   the token has not yet been generated.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with this issue, was not receiving firebase push notification on the IOS device ABOVE IOS-10 because firebase token might be longer than the data type you chose it to be stored with.
Check your datatype for the token column. I Have converted from varchar to text and it works and saved our day.

Regards,
Gurminder