# iOS Swift Firebase InstanceID token returns Nil at first time

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, instanceid

I am using Firebase notification in my app. When I install my app for first time `FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()` returns nil, but it won't return nil at next time. Everything is done perfect except this.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
import FirebaseInstanceID
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, FIRMessagingDelegate
{

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
{
        //Configuring Firebase
        FIRApp.configure()
if #available(iOS 10.0, *)
        {
            print("Test")
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .sound, .alert]) { (granted, error) in
                if granted
                {
                    //self.registerCategory()
                }
            }
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self
        }
        else
        {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.firInstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)
        return true
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)
    {
        FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
        FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.prod)
    }
func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification)
    {
        if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()
        {
            print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
        }
        // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
        connectToFcm()
    }

    func connectToFcm()
    {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
            if (error != nil)
            {
                print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
            }
            else
            {
                print("Connected to FCM.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In Remote Page I am Calling Firebase InstanceID Token

```
let token = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()
```

But at first time it return nil value.

Comment: Can you show some code what you had try out!

Comment: Similar question with answer in the comments: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40859930/4815718

Comment: @BobSnyder how to add an observer for the key firInstanceIDTokenRefresh for retrieving the most updated token

Comment: Someone else will have to answer.  I don't know.

Comment: are you using APNS and FCM or only used the FCM

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Using both APNS and FCM

Comment: show ur code....

Comment: change the order of ` FIRApp.configure()` at the end of launch

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik which means before returning true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the order of `FIRApp.configure()` and try once, for more information you can get the sample [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/MessagingExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift)

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
               didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

// Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
// show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
// [START register_for_notifications]
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
  // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

  let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
    options: authOptions,
    completionHandler: {_, _ in })

  // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
  FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

} else {
  let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
  UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
  application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
}

application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

// [END register_for_notifications]
FIRApp.configure()

// [START add_token_refresh_observer]
// Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
    selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
    name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh,
    object: nil)
// [END add_token_refresh_observer]
return true
}
```

on that delegate check once the token is comes or not

```
func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
      //  print("refresh token call")
        guard let contents = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()
        else {
            return
        }
           // let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!
            print("InstanceID token: \(contents)")

           // UserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().set(contents, forKey: "deviceToken");
            // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.

            connectToFcm()

    }
```

finally connect the FCM like

```
func connectToFcm() {
// Won't connect since there is no token
guard FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() != nil else {
  return
}

// Disconnect previous FCM connection if it exists.
FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()

FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
  if error != nil {
    print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
  } else {
    print("Connected to FCM.")
  }
}
  }
```

Comment: @KavinKumarArumugam - which line you modified,

Comment: Sorry still I am facing this problem. Still FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() returns nil at first time. I modified `tokenRefreshNotification` and `connectToFcm()`

Comment: Why is this accepted if still didn't solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Finally I got some solution for this. Firebase will take some time to connect to FCM. So what I did is, I make my code to update after 5 seconds if `FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()` returns nil. Within 5 seconds Firebase will connected to FCM. This is not the perfect solution but now this is the only way to solve it.

Comment: Could you show the code of this solution, please? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

> You need to add the line of code in the `AppDelegate File`
>   `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function`

Call the **application.registerForRemoteNotifications()** before the **FirebaseApp.configure()**

1. Like this.
        **application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        FirebaseApp.configure()**